# FiveM lua: spoof source

Tags: lua, fivem

```lua
RegisterServerEvent('XD')
AddEventHandler('XD', function()
    print(source)
end)
```

TriggerServerEvent("XD")

is there a way to spoof your source from the server when you trigger an event.

i though of doing this when you trigger

```lua
TriggerServerEvent("XD", source = '200' -- [[this is the source the server will think you are]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua is a language of reference. If Lua cannot see something, it cannot use it.

Typically, as a rule of thumb: *if you do not define the variable, you cannot use it*. There are exceptions to this, which are the functions that the global variable provides to you, like `print`.

We also see another issue: you try to define `source` like a table, but you don't give it a table to rest in.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

#### #1. Give `source` it's own argument

Remove `source` and add `source` as a argument to `function(...)`

Server:

```lua
RegisterServerEvent('XD')
AddEventHandler('XD', function(source)
    print(source)
end)
```

Client:

```lua
TriggerServerEvent("XD", '200')
```

#### #2. Create a table for `source` to hang out in

To start with, give the `TriggerServerEvent` a nice cozy table.

```lua
TriggerServerEvent("XD", {} )
```

Then put `source` into it.

```lua
TriggerServerEvent("XD", { source = '200' })
```

Now, on the server, we need an argument for the table:

```lua
RegisterServerEvent('XD')
AddEventHandler('XD', function(args)
    print(args)
end)
```

However, since `args` is a table, and we want `source`, we have to *index* it.

```lua
RegisterServerEvent('XD')
AddEventHandler('XD', function(args)
    print(args.source) -- or args["source"]
end)
```

---